# datetime module does not work, time is incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time

I added a time module, and the date is correct, but the time for some reason is completely off from PST. I doubled checked the timezone and it says it is PST, but the time is still completely wrong.

```
import time

clock = time.gmtime()
hm = time.strftime("%X", clock)
date = time.strftime("%x", clock)
print(time.strftime("%Z", clock))
print(date)
print(hm)
```

and it just prints out the bottom, but the actual PST time is 3:21, how can I fix this?

```
Pacific Standard Time
07/30/20
22:21:18
```

Comment: Since you chose gmtime, are you looking to get UTC?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.localtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html).

In the link, there are all the methods you need.

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies in the fact that `.gmtime()` may not be time zone specific.

To get the time specific to the timezone, try using `.localtime()`:

```py
import time

t = time.localtime()

current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
print(current_time)
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `gmtime()` get you the UTC time, **in the UTC timezone**, without storing time zone information. You may want to `print(repr(clock))` to get more information on what a *time* represent (with all internal data). As you see, using `localtime()` you get same information, just in an other timezone (and not timezone information).

So you have a time and you print such time, without giving the system information about which time zone you are.

Note: `%x` and `%X` (and most of time formatting strings) uses "locale" (in description) not as local timezone, but as local formatting, e.g. if using for "hh:mm" or "h:mm pm", etc.

Note: only recently `time` module gained timezone information, but it will uses only when explicitly given, not to break old programs.

In general, I would recommend you to use `datetime` module: better interface, and easier to spot if a time is timezone aware (and which timezone).